# How to replace a text sequence that includes "\n" in a text file

Tags: regex, bash, csv, tr

This may sound duplicated, but I can't make this works.

**Consider:**

_ = space
- = minus sign

`particle_little.csv` is a file of this form:

```
waste line to be deleted
__data__data__data
_-data__data_-data
__data_-data__data
```

**I need to get** a standard csv format in `particle_std.csv`, like this:

```
data,data,data
-data,data,-data
data,-data,data
```

**I am trying to** use `tail` and `tr` to do that conversion, here I split the command:

1. `tail -n +2 particle_little.csv` to delete the first line
2. `| tr -s ' '`  to remove duplicated spaces
3. `| tr '/\b\n \b/' '\n'` to delete the very beginning space
4. `| tr ' ' ','` to change spaces for commas
5. `> particle_std.csv` to put it in a output file

**But I get this** (without the 4th step):

```
data
data
data
-data
...
```

Finally, the file is huge, so it is almost impossible to open in editors (I know there are super editors that maybe can)

Comment: In my opinion, you're trying to use the wrong tools for the job; funnily enough, it doesn't work very well.  Are you constrained to use just `tr` and `tail`?  Or do you just need to get the job done and those are the first tools that came to hand?  Does the 'data' portion ever contain spaces?  Presumably not.

Comment: I need to get the output, and yes, those were the first tools I found (so, I'm new in their usage)

Comment: by the way, the file is huge

Comment: Huge files aren't a problem as long as you don't try to suck it all into memory at once, and as long as you don't try to write it down too many pipes.  Zero pipes is best; one pipe isn't a major problem; twenty pipes could be a problem (it still might be correct, but usually isnt').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you used awk:

```
$ cat file
waste line to be deleted
  data  data  data
 -data  data -data
  data -data  data
$ awk -v OFS=, '{ $1 = $1 } NR > 1' file
data,data,data
-data,data,-data
data,-data,data
```

The script sets the output field separator `OFS` to `,` and reassigns the first field to itself `$1 = $1`, causing awk to touch each line (and replace the spaces with commas). Lines after the first, where `NR > 1`, are printed (the default action is to print the line).

Comment: Oh! man, that is magic and at the same time makes funny my solution... thanks, can you please explain me the options you used?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain it a bit more, is there anything that is still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm reading you right - ignore lines that *don't* start with whitespace. Comma separate everything else.

I'd suggest `perl`:

```
perl -lane 'next unless /^\s/; print join ",", @F';
```

This, when given:

```
waste line to be deleted
  data  data  data
 -data  data -data
  data -data  data
```

On `STDIN` (Or specified in a filename) outputs:

```
data,data,data
-data,data,-data
data,-data,data
```

This is because:

`-l` strips linefeeds (and replaces them after each `print`);

`-a` autosplits on any whitespace

`-n` wraps it in a `while ( <> ) {` loop which iterates line by line - functionally it means it works just like `sed`/`grep`/`tr` and reads `STDIN` or files specified as args.

`-e` allows specifying a perl snippet.

In this case:

- skip any lines that don't start with `\s` or any whitespace.
- any other lines, join the fields (`@F` generated by `-a`) with `,` as delimiter. (This auto-inserts a linefeed because `-l`)

Then you can either redirect the output to a file (`>output.csv`) or use `-i.bak` to edit inplace.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `sed` or `awk` for this:

```
sed -e 1d -e 's/^  *//' -e 's/  */,/g'
```

One way to do it in Awk is:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { next }
     { pad=""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%s%s", pad, $i; pad="," } print "" }'
```

but there's a better way to do it in Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=","} NR == 1 { next } { $1 = $1; print }' data
```

The BEGIN block sets the output field separator; the assignment `$1 = $1;` forces Awk to rework the output line; the `print` prints it.

I've left the first Awk version around because it shows there's more than one way to do it, and in some circumstances, such methods can be useful.  But for this task, the second Awk version is better — simpler, more compact (and isomorphic with [Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376124/15168)).